# Integration of 0

Tags: integration

We know that derivative of a constant function is zero. As integration is inverse process of differentiation the integral of zero must be a constant function. But when we integrate the function f(x)=0   using 0=1×0 and taking out 0 before the integral sign as 0 is a constant we get the integral to be 0×(x) which is evidently zero  and not always an arbitrary constant function. Why is this happening? Am i misunderstanding something? Plz help me.

Answer (score 3):

When doing indefinite integration, never forget the constant, i.e.:
$$\int f'(x)\,dx =f(x)+c,\quad c\in \mathbb{R}.$$
i.e integration is an inverse to differentiation up to a constant.

Comment: The question was - why we can't write $\int f'(x) dx = \int 0*f'(x) dx = 0 * \int f'(x) dx = 0* (f(x)+C) = 0$ ?

Comment: Ok i understand it now so the indefinite integral of zero is a constant when that constant of integration C is added. Thanks